# Problems calling a WCF service from a WPF xbap client app in another host

Tags: wpf, wcf, xbap

I am new to WCF, I have developed a WCF service that returns a string with a required value, I publish it in IIS on the same computer and then I created a WPF client app, I tested it in Debug mode and worked fine, I tried publishing the client app in the IIS and tested it in the same machine and everything was ok, It's a full trust app.

The problem is when I try to execute the client app in another machine, the thing is that from the machine I can access the service:

```
http://ip_address/OASWS.Utilities/Service1.svc
```

and there is no problem, and I can execute the app:

```
http://address/OASWS.Utilities.BrowserClient/UtilitiesBrowserClient.xbap
```

and the application is executed with no problems, but when the app tries to execute any function from the service I get the following error inmediatly:

```
Startup URI: http://ip_address/OASWS.Utilities.BrowserClient/UtilitiesBrowserClient.xbap

Application identity: http://ip_address/OASWS.Utilities.BrowserClient/UtilitiesBrowserClient.xbap#UtilitiesBrowserClient.xbap, Version=1.0.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5273a5e76684b5e7, processorArchitecture=msil/UtilitiesBrowserClient.exe, Version=1.0.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5273a5e76684b5e7, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32
```

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: type 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedFault' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.SerializeObject(Object obj, MemoryStream stm)
   at System.AppDomain.Serialize(Object o)
   at System.AppDomain.MarshalObject(Object o)

And I don't have a clue on what  could be happening or where does that error comes from, because the only this the service returns is a simple string.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar behaviour, when code inside the WCF service throws an exception other than FaultException - again, only in an XBAP.

Comment: Hello Julia, thanks for your reply, I changed my client to asp.net Web Application and didn't have any problems.